# Calling LINQ methods on IEnumerable results in empty List

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I'm trying to implement pagination on an ASP.NET Repeater control by using LINQ on a Datatable. I expected this code to give me back a page of rows based on parameters `currentPage` and `pageSize`:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> allRows = allRecordsDataTable.AsEnumerable();
List<DataRow> pageOfRows = new List<DataRow>();

if (allRows.Any())
{
    pageOfRows = allRows
        .OrderBy(dr => dr[3])
        .Reverse()
        .Skip(currentPage * pageSize)
        .Take(pageSize)
        .ToList();
 }

 if (pageOfRows.Count > 0)
     repeater.DataSource = pageOfRows.CopyToDataTable();
 else
     repeater.DataSource = allRecordsDataTable;
```

The code falls into the if block, so the IEnumerable does indeed contain DataRows.  And yet, the List has a count of zero after the linq calls are made, so the repeater is always bound to `allRecordsDataTable`.  Am I misunderstanding how IEnumerable works?

P.S. The `.orderby()` is sorting by a column of Datetime

Comment: It's probably the `.Skip`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `currentPage * pageSize` is higher than the number of elements in `allRows`, you'll get no records in pageOfRows.

`Skip` will not throw an exception if you inadvertently "skip" right past all your records. It'll just return an empty set.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> If source contains fewer than count elements, an empty IEnumerable is returned.

Place a breakpoint and check the number of records in `pageOfRows` and the result of `currentPage * pageSize`.

*(Looking at your code, this is the most probable cause.)*

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use orderbydescending instead of orderby and then reverse

Answer (score 0):

It could be either `currentPage * pageSize` is greater than allRows collection or `pageSize` is 0.